# Definition of conditional probability for the intersection of 2 events - am I right?

Tags: probability

Am I right saying that (assuming that $P(A)>0, P(B)>0, P(C)>0$)

$P(A\cap B|C)=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}?$

Comment: That is the definition of conditional probability (applied to the events $A\cap B$ and $C$).

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. To help see for yourself, let's call the event $A \cap B$ by a new name, $E$. The definition of conditional probability gives us that
\begin{equation*}
P(E \mid C) = \frac{P(E \cap C)}{P(C)}
\end{equation*}
We also know that $E \cap C = (A \cap B) \cap C = A \cap B \cap C$, as events, so we get the result you ask about.

(Also, note that we only need to assume $P(C) > 0$. The result is perfectly valid when $P(A) = 0$ and/or $P(B) = 0$.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about giving it a new name, thanks.

Comment: If you write the equality as a product: $P(E|C)P(C)=P(E\cap C)$ then condition  $P(C)>0$ can be left out as well.

Comment: @drhab True, but writing that equality only defines a value for $P(E \mid C)$ when $P(C)$ is nonzero.

Comment: True. In fact a suitable value for the conditional probability can be chosen then. If e.g. $P(X=c)=0$ and $X,Y$ are independent rvs then we can go for $P(Y\in B|X=c)=P(Y\in B)$.

Answer (score -1):

This is comes from defination of conditional probability for two sets, you can also try for more than three and any finite as well infinite numbers of sets.as i think well?